# Does Cramer's Rule give fake solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $$\begin{bmatrix}
>  1    &   \alpha  &     \alpha^2 \\ \alpha &  1    &   \alpha \\    \alpha^2   &  \alpha  & 1 \\   \end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}
>  x \\ y \\ z \\   \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
>  1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\   \end{bmatrix}$$ 
>   If the system of given linear equations, has infinitely many solutions, then find $\alpha$.

I use the Cramer's Rule, like the way it is used [here](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/algebra/algebra-ii/linear-equations-in-three-variables/linear-equations-solutions-using-determinants-with-three-variables).

So I define $\begin{bmatrix}
 1    &   \alpha  &     \alpha^2 \\ \alpha &  1    &   \alpha \\    \alpha^2   &  \alpha  & 1 \\   \end{bmatrix}= \Delta$ which should be equal to zero (Cramer's Rule). Solving this I get two values of $\alpha$ : 1 and -1 .

Now we proceed to calculate $\Delta_1$,$\Delta_2$,$\Delta_3$ as follows:

$\Delta_1=\begin{bmatrix}
 1    &   \alpha  &     \alpha^2 \\ -1 &  1    &   \alpha \\    1   &  \alpha  & 1 \\   \end{bmatrix}$
$\Delta_2=\begin{bmatrix}
 1    &   1  &     \alpha^2 \\ \alpha &  -1    &   \alpha \\   \alpha^2   &  1  & 1 \\   \end{bmatrix}$
$\Delta_3=\begin{bmatrix}
 1    &   \alpha  &     1 \\ \alpha &  1    &   -1 \\    \alpha^2   &  \alpha  & 1 \\   \end{bmatrix}$

If I put $ \alpha = 1 $ and $\alpha = -1$ in the above matrices, we get all the determinants equal to zero ($\Delta_1=\Delta_2=\Delta_3=0$). So I conclude both 1 and -1 should be a solution to the question.

Now the problem arises as I inspect the answer. The equations formed when I put $\alpha = 1$ will be:
$x+y+z=1 \\ x+y+z=-1 \\ x+y+z=1$

Here the first two planes are parallel to each other. That means they donot intersect and must imply inconsistency. So I don't have infinite solutions for $\alpha = 1$. So the sole answer would be $\alpha = -1$ .

My Question is why does $\alpha = 1$ satisfy the equations but does not satisfy the problem. Why does solving give $\alpha=1$  when it isn't a solution?

And do I need to do this kind of inspection for every equation that I solve with this method? (Since it tends to give superfluous answers).

All help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I thought it would be best if I clarified my question a little bit more.

Cramer's Rule tells us that :

For a *Unique Solution* $\Delta \ne 0$ (we don't care about the other deltas)  And the solutions will be $\Delta_1/\Delta$ $\Delta_2/\Delta$ , $\Delta_3/\Delta$

For *no solution* $\Delta = 0$ and atleast one of the other Deltas is non-zero.

For infinite solutions $\Delta = \Delta_1 = \Delta_2 = \Delta_3 = 0$.

Now since $\Delta$ in the question is zero, there are no unique solutions. That leaves us with two options: either no-solution or infinite-solutions.

So equating all the other Deltas to zero simultaneously I get $\alpha = 1,-1$ as stated before.

But then why does $\alpha = 1$ give me no solutions.

I few minutes of stroll below and you'll see that this method isn't that popular (especially the infinite one). I don't know why. But I'm sure somebody out there will definitely follow on.

Comment: Why do you set $\Delta$ to be equal to zero as your first step?

Comment: Look at this section, especially about the systems with three or more equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Incompatible_and_indeterminate_cases

Comment: @Sobi for infinite solutions $\Delta = \Delta_1 = \Delta_2 = \Delta_3 = 0$

Comment: You obtain Cramer's rule by multiplying the system by the adjugate matrix of the system. If the determinant of the system is zero, then this is akind of multiplying by $0$ (strictly speaking a matrix that is a zero divisor got multiplied by a matrix that annihilates it). Notice that an incompatible equation $0=1$ can be turn compatible by multiplying by $0$, since $0\times 0=0\times 1$  is compatible. That is why Cramer's rule gives you candidate systems with infinite solutions. You then need to check directly if the original system was compatible or not.

Comment: People are pointing out that Cramer's rule doesn't say what you want.  The answer is thus:  no, Cramer's rule isn't wrong; you are using the wrong rule, and it doesn't really matter *why* you're using it.  The page to which you link says "If the denominator determinant, $D$ [your $\Delta$], has a value of zero, then the system is either inconsistent or dependent."  This is the phenomenon you have observed:  *if* the system is underdetermined, then $\Delta = 0$; but one cannot conclude the converse, and, in fact, a system with $\Delta = 0$ may be inconsistent.

Comment: Where are you getting this statement of Cramer's rule?  So far as I know, Cramer's rule only applies when the determinant is nonzero.  This is the statement on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule)

Comment: @saulspatz he is correct in thinking that a nonzero determinant for the square matrix means exactly one solution, so he insists on determinant zero. He seems completely unwilling to admit that Cramer's rule stops at exactly that point. Once the determinant is demanded zero, Cramer's rule does not apply and other methods must be used, to continue at all.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, that is what I've always understood, and I started to write a comment saying precisely that.  Then I wondered if he had some other statement he was trying to apply.

Comment: @saulspatz I don't know either. However, this seems to fit in the general area of "contest questions." We get tons of these, where the student has only a dim notion of what is going on, but wants to do the problem as quickly as possible, as an actual contest will have time limits. He does say below one of the answers that he will look up Gauss elimination; good, but it means that has been unknown so far...

Comment: @WillJagy I hadn't thought about contests; that makes sense.  It also furnishes a possible explanation of some very strange posts I seen in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The Cramer's Rule says that if the system has only one solution ($\Delta \ne0$), then solution is given by,

$$x_i=\frac{\Delta x_i}{\Delta}$$

So if $\Delta=0$ then you can't use Cramer's Rule.

In general you have that $(\Delta)x_i=\Delta x_i$ so, if $\Delta=0$ and $\Delta x_i=0$ you can't say anything about the solution.

Comment: I specifically want infinite solutions so $\Delta = \Delta_1 = \Delta_2 = \Delta_3 = 0$ Thanks for the answer though +1

Comment: @SmarthBansal: In your case you have to use Gauss elimination or something equivalent

Comment: Though I'm not sure why my method fails.  But I will read about Gauss elimination as you say.

Comment: @SmarthBansal: Your method fails because he is not valid when $\Delta =0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your determinant should not be $0$ because you want to divide other determinants by it.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1    &   \alpha  &     \alpha^2 \\ \alpha &  1    &   \alpha \\    \alpha^2   &  \alpha  & 1 \\   \end{bmatrix} = (\alpha ^2 -1)(\alpha ^3 -1)$$ Find other deerminants and divide to get your answers in terms of $\alpha$

Comment: I specifically want infinite solutions so $\Delta = \Delta_1 = \Delta_2 = \Delta_3 = 0$. should hold. Thanks for writing this answer +1

Answer (score 1):

It is something wrong with the source you are using. It says

> The system is dependent if all the determinants have a value of zero.

It is wrong. A simple counterexample: the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
is obviously inconsistent, however, all the determinants are zero
$$
\Delta=0,\quad\Delta_x=\begin{vmatrix}1 & 0\\1 & 0\end{vmatrix}=0,\quad\Delta_y=\begin{vmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 1\end{vmatrix}=0.
$$
Another example:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & 0\\0 & \alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Here
$$
\Delta=\alpha^2,\quad \Delta_x=\Delta_y=\alpha.
$$
For $\alpha=0$ we have as above all the determinants are zero, however, the calculation of e.g. $x$ gives
$$
x=\frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta}=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2}.
$$
When $\alpha\to 0$ we get that the zero in the denominator is "more zero" then in the numerator, so we get $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ not existing limit.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer! I agree your examples do support your answer. But this isn't the only place where I've seen this sort of method. And it does work well for many other equations that I've seen........

Comment: ........For example: $2x + Py + 6z = 8$; $x+2y+Qz = 5$; $x+y+3z = 4$ ; Here if you solve for $\Delta = \Delta_1 = \Delta_2 = \Delta_3 = 0$ you get $P=2$, $Q=3$ which does really cause the equations to have infinite solutions.

Comment: Do you think this method might be missing some boundaries, which invalidates the examples you mentioned and many more alike?

Comment: @SmarthBansal The method cannot be used when all the determinants are zeros. The standard solution is to calculate those exceptional zeros where $\Delta=0$ and then for each particular exceptional value perform elimination, i.e. solve the linear system.